# Can't see balance of the tokens of the smart contract in remix when run the seeBalance function

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

pragma solidity =0.7.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

interface IERC20 {
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
    external
    returns (bool);

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
```

}

contract MultiSwap {

```
address public owner;
address public balance;

constructor() {
    owner == msg.sender;
}

address public constant routerAddress =
    0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564;
ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter = ISwapRouter(routerAddress);

address public constant SHUBYDAI = 0xe742A911ffFAEc86786bd2246Dd035F6Aa55aE2B;
address public constant SHUBYUSDC = 0xA61C9829209b75741bBB9f682483B3A4C3e4E924;

IERC20 public shubyToken = IERC20(SHUBYDAI);

function swapExactInputMultihop(uint amountIn) 
    external
    returns (uint amountOut)
{
    shubyToken.transfer(
        address(this),
        amountIn
    );
    shubyToken.approve(address(swapRouter), amountIn);

    ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params = ISwapRouter
    .ExactInputParams({
        path: abi.encodePacked(
            SHUBYDAI,
            uint24(3000),
            SHUBYUSDC,
            uint24(3000),
            SHUBYDAI
        ),
        recipient: msg.sender,
        deadline: block.timestamp,
        amountIn: amountIn,
        amountOutMinimum: 0
    });
    amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);
}

function transferIERC20(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 amount) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can use this function");
    uint256 erc20Balance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    require(amount <= erc20Balance, "balance is low");
    token.transfer(to, amount);
}

function SeeBalance(IERC20 token) public view {
   IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
   
}
```

}

when i try to interact with this contract on remix and i try to run the seeBalance function it doesn't work, the message i get is.

[block: txIndex:]from: 0x241...8Be5fto: 0xFC4c5cE47f2E9361B28E8f6B486668dB61730A81 0xFC4...30A81value: 0 weidata: 0xbbb...5ae2blogs: 0hash:

decoded output   -

i have transfered 4000 ShubyDAI which is the token i want to see the token for but i dont get a value.

Could someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code should be as below.

```
function SeeBalance(IERC20 token) public view returns (uint256) {
   return IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
}
```